# Significant delays when opening flag dialog?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flag-dialog

I'm consistently receiving significant delays on Stack Overflow when opening the flag dialog on *questions*. Delays do not occur on any other StackExchange site I have checked. This started a couple days ago (as far as I can tell).

Delays occur not only when loading the initial screen, but also when loading the submenus. This is slightly confusing for a couple seconds (until you're used to it) since it appears as if the flag dialog has simply vanished.

What's going on here? I demand to know, otherwise somebody will be very upset.

Not me. I'm not going to get that upset over something like this.

But someone will.

---

Specs (though I know of several others who have this issue):

```
Windows 7 64-bit
Chrome Version 30.0.1599.69m
    Ping: 31ms
Download: 6.88mbps
  Upload: 1.07mbps
```

Comment: For me, there's a long delay when flagging *questions*, but no delay when flagging *answers*.

Comment: @Pang Good point. I've edited the question.

Comment: Same for me. Started a few days ago, can't remember exactly when.

Comment: I'm glad to know it's not you who would be upset... ;-)

Comment: I just tested, and noticed it as well (for questions; don't know about answers). [Here's a screenshot of the request timings for the initial screen, and for the "it should be closed for another reason..." submenu](http://i.imgur.com/yFMIJKd.png).

Comment: Answer flagging seems pretty speedy, I think its just question flagging (and only on the main site for me, not meta)

Comment: I also experience the same problem when closing a question. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199978/loading-time-of-3s-for-close-flag-link) is a screenshot of Chrome's dev console showing 6 seconds for loading a JS file!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Some backend changes to get closing and flag dialogs into a more declarative version (in preparation for adding them to the android app) ended up causing a couple of rather expensive queries to run when they didn't use to.

This was fixed over the last couple deploys, flagging and closing should be pretty much the same speed they were before the refactoring.

Comment: [This one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/199978/152859) should also be marked completed.