# Loading time of 3s for 'close'/'flag' link

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, close-dialog, flag-dialog

**How to reproduce (at least for me):**

- Open a question (it musn't be closed yet)

  1. Clicking on 'close' shows me the loading animation (the rectangles) for about 3 - 4 seconds.
  2. Clicking on 'flag' also shows me the loading animation, but even longer: 4 seconds was the longest time period I could measure!

**My system:**

- IE 10 and Chrome 30 (both show the same problem)
- If the OS matters, it's *Windows 8 Pro 64-bit*.

Is the loading time intended behaviour? Did anyone else notice that change?

Note that all other parts of the StackOverflow website show great performance!

Screenshot from Chrome network tab:

> [image]

Comment: Started seeing slowdown in close dialog opening times a few days ago.

Comment: Firefox 24.0 on windows 7 same problem

Comment: status-norepro on Mobile Safari

Comment: Reproduced on Windows 7 SP1, Aurora 26.0a2.

Comment: Even slower here (6 seconds). I assume they forgot to cache something. With millions of records, querying the database every time will cause exactly such problems. Cache for the rescue!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Wow, all those "its caching" problems seem really justified now

Comment: @RichardTingle server side cache is the real engine behind Stack Overflow super speed, they cache *everything*, so I'm surprised they missed something this time. :)